# Create a link to a cart to be used in emails

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to be able to create a link to an anonymous users cart, and send this to the user in an email. When the user clicks this link, he should be taken to his cart. (As part of an "abandoned cart" feature)

However, in Drupal Commerce, the cart of anonymous users are identified by the session, so if the person opens the email in another browser the cart will be empty (or contain whetever he put into his cart in that browser). So it is not good enough to make the link point to `/cart`.

Is there a way in Drupal Commerce to make a link to a specific cart-ID?

(Something like `https://mysite.com/set-current-cart?cartId=<cartId>`)

---

If not, i'm thinking of creating a Controller, which takes a cart-ID as parameter, and have the links in the emails point to this controller. Clicking the link would make the cart "belong" to the current user. Is it possible to "transfer ownership" of a cart from one anonymous user (in one browser) to another anonymous user (in another browser)?

There are of course some security precautions: If the link is just on the form `https://mysite.com/set-current-cart?cartId=<cartId>`, then everyone could steal each others carts. So it should at least be encrypted somehow. Ideas or best-practices?

(Alternatively, one could instead create a new cart, and copy the content of the original cart to this new cart - then the old cart will still exist, so users cannot steal carts from eachother. Perhaps this is safer?)

Comment: Usually sites only do this kind of emailing functionality when the user has an account.

How will you know the users email address to email if they're shopping anonymously? Do you have a email address field somewhere and will only be targeting users who get that far ( have entered this email) in the booking process?

Cleanest and simplest solution is to disable anonymous checkout and require Drupal accounts to order

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the idea is to only send an email to the anonymous users, when they have provided an email address *and* have accepted to receive emails from us, as part of the checkout flow. (Yes, it would be simpler to limit it to only logged in users, but almost all the users are anonymous users)

Comment: Carts deal with PHP sessions (for anonymous users).
If you want to do such a thing to anonymous user, then you'll have to build a custom feature to generate a token or something similar to store as a drupal state variable (for exemple) and then when the user receive the mail with that unique token, your custom feature will be able to build an instance of a pre-configured cart.